# How To decode url_title() function in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I will get back uri segment after i use url_title() and pass to url. i try use rawurldecode() but not perfect. example, i have

```
$a = 'Handphone -Charger -Handsfree -Kabel data -Buku panduan -Kartu Garansi ';
```

and i pass to url with `url_title($a);` , result is ok

> Handphone0D0A-Charger0D0A-Handsfree0D0A-Kabel-data0D0A-Buku-panduan0D0A-Kartu-Garansi

i try use `rawurldecode($this->uri->segment(10))`
result :

> Handphone0D0A Charger0D0A Handsfree0D0A Kabel data0D0A Buku panduan0D0A Kartu Garansi

i want :

> Handphone Charger Handsfree Kabel data Buku panduan Kartu Garansi

how i do that?
whether there is a function available in CodeIgniter?

Comment: So your original string has hyphens, but after encoding and decoding, you don't want those hyphens? Is that correct?

Comment: store the original `$a` and the slug when you create it... look up by slug

Answer (score 3):

As you want a string that is slightly different after the encoding/decoding, i.e. without the hyphens and newline characters, you should first strip your string from those, before doing any encoding. So there are three steps:

#### 1. Clean

With [**preg_replace**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) you can remove newlines and hyphens as follows:

```php
$a = preg_replace('/\s+\-/s', ' ', trim($a));
```

The value of *$a* is now clean:

> Handhone Charger Handsfree Kabel data Buku panduan Kartu Garansi

#### 2. Encode

Instead of using `url_title($a)`, use the PHP native function **urlencode** to pass *$a* on the URL:

```
urlencode($a)
```

The value on the URL is then:

> Handhone+Charger+Handsfree+Kabel+data+Buku+panduan+Kartu+Garansi

The `+` signs represent spaces, and they convert back well with the third step:

#### 3. Decode

With this procedure you need to use **urldecode**, not **rawurldecode**:

```
urldecode($this->uri->segment(10))
```

This gives:

> Handhone Charger Handsfree Kabel data Buku panduan Kartu Garansi

Comment: You're welcome. If this answers your question, please accept it.